# I want to display words separate from a sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

Our teacher asked us this question:

"Get a sentence from the user and display it back with one word per line."

This is easy however I'm not allowed to use .split, any forms of lists, and any forms of loops.

Comment: Hint: [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sentence = "Get a sentence from the user and display it back with one word per line."
for character in range(len(sentence)):
    if sentence[character] == ' ' or sentence[character] == '.' or sentence[character] == ',':
        print("")
    else:
        print(sentence[character], end='')
```

OUTPUT:

```
Get
a
sentence
from
the
user
and
display
it
back
with
one
word
per
line
```